# DJ native Swing and Netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans-7

I want to Integrate DJ Native Swing to my Netbeans installation so i can use it in my project.

I have found a [tutorial](http://netbeans.dzone.com/how-to-nb-djnative-swing) in for doing so, in the tutorial the writers asks to make a library wrapper module. Can some one please guide me in simple steps how can i make one?

Also why can't DJ Native swing be imported as a library, why all this fuss ?

Comment: Just for curiosity: did it work?

Answer (score 0):

See '[What is a library wrapper module and how do I use it?](http://wiki.netbeans.org/DevFaqWrapperModules)'

> You can use File > New Project > NetBeans Modules > Library Wrapper Module to make a library wrapper.

You have to create a Module Suite prior to the creation of the library wrapper. The suite acts as a container for the library wrapper. Create the module suite via File > New Project > NetBeans Modules > Module Suite.

The benefit of wrapping an external library by this mechanism is to reference that library as a regular module in your netbeans module suite.

I do not think DJ Native Swing cannot be linked as a regular library, but there may be (I do not say there have to be) some subtle modfications necessary to the steps described in the tutorial.

Comment: Thanks, i have tried to regularly link but when i import its utilities netbeans show errors.

Comment: I still could not get it, i tried to File > New Project > NetBeans Modules > Library Wrapper Module :: When i browse to DJ native jar file and select it it goes to next process but ask for a regular suite. It does not go any further as it could not find a regular suite

Comment: Ok now I see. It seems you have to create a Module Suite prior to the creation of the library wrapper. Create it via File > New Project > NetBeans Modules > Module Suite.

Comment: Ok . I did so and added it to new module suite, now what should be done. Should i compile it? sorry for such questions i am totally new to netbeans.

Comment: now you add the libary wrapper and continue with the tutorial.